# xamarin android real time notifications app uber similar

Tags: android, xamarin, notifications, real-time

I'm developing an application on Xamarin Android similar to uber but I need to make real-time notifications of travel request, cancellation and location, any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several choices you can choose:

**1. Firebase**

You can  to use Firebase to provide real-time notifications.
By using only two Firebase features, you can create real-time notifications for users: the Firebase `Realtime database` for web users , and Firebase `Cloud Messaging` for Android users.

What the Firebase Realtime database provides us with is the ability to save, retrieve and sync our data with our NoSQL cloud database. We can sync data across all clients in real time. The Firebase Realtime Database is simply a cloud-hosted NoSQL database and the data is stored as a JSON and synchronized in real time to every connected client.

For more details, you can check: https://www.atlantbh.com/blog/using-firebase-provide-real-time-notifications/

**2. SignalR**

Azure Mobile Services has SignalR integrated, and Azure Mobile Services provide a SDK for client apps, I suppose it is provide out-of-the box.

> You will find many capabilities included in Mobile Services and
>   readily available for your Web API. Mobile push notifications,
>   real-time notifications with SignalR (auto-scaled out), social auth
>   for your consumer apps, offline data sync for occasionally connected
>   scenarios, to name a few.

For more details: 
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2013/11/01/How-To-Use-SignalR-in-iOS-and-Android-Apps.aspx?Page=2

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/30/real-time-with-asp-net-signalr-and-azure-mobile-net-backend/

https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-cn/blog/azure-mobile-services-why-should-asp-net-developers-care/#HighValueCapabilities

**Samples:**

https://github.com/gshackles/RealTimeGallery

http://saramgsilva.github.io/NotificationHubs/

**3.PubNub**

Live Notifications of it keep everyone, and everything, realtime with live notifications across HTTP, SMS, FCM, APNS2 and more.

For more: https://www.pubnub.com/solutions/live-notifications/

**4. Pusher**

PubNub and Pusher are all offerring real-time infrastructure as a service and all the benefits that come with that. Both of these solutions are pub/sub. Pusher also offers an additional event abstraction: Evented PubSub.
For more: https://www.pubnub.com/developers/

Comment: Thanks, is there any other option than firebase?

Comment: @mauroy   I have updated the answer, you can check it.Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need to know.

Comment: So do uber or whatsapp use one of these, just curious